# How to tranfer all data from SQL server to Azure API for FHIR database(managed server)?

Tags: azure, hl7-fhir, fhir-server-for-azure

I'm trying to transfer all of my data from SQL server to azure api for fhir.(Managed Server)
Any idea what should be the starting point for this task. I have thousands of patients in the SQL server.
I need to transfer all of my current data into azure cosmos db. Also, our EMR stores all the data into SQL Server. So once I'm done with this bulk transfer any idea how can I transfer this new data into azure cosmos db every day.

I will really appreciate your help on this. Please let me know if you have any questions.

I have tried to convert my data into FHIR resources. I can insert them manuall into FHIR server. But I cannot do this for all the data.

Comment: Is this what you're looking for? https://azure.microsoft.com/en-us/updates/documentdb-data-migration-tool/

Some other documentation is here: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/cosmos-db/migration-choices

Comment: @Ashavan I don't know. Do we have to write ETL process? Cosmos DB and my SQL Server Schema is different.

Answer (score 0):

If you're looking to transfer this data every day, keeping both in sync, you probably need to look at some Middleware to handle this for you, such as Mirth Connect.

A Mirth channel could look for new records in SQL Server, transform the data into a bundle of FHIR resources, then either pass the bundle on to an API of your own which handles the FHIR server update, or run the update itself inside the channel.

The downside with this approach is that the FHIR transformer plugin for Mirth requires a commercial license. You could also use the open source version of Mirth, transform to HL7, then run the HL7 files through the open source Microsoft FHIR Converter to produce FHIR resources, then run the insert/update yourself. (More work on your end.)